# VPC Network Upgrade

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vpc

I'm trying to upgrade our legacy network on GCP to a VPC network with this command: gcloud beta compute networks update default --switch-to-custom-subnet-mode but I get this error in response:

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.networks.update) The first 2 IPs in this network's range 10.240.0.0/16 must be in used.

I thought that this meant that I need to use 10.240.0.2 and 10.240.0.3 since they are the first two usable IPs in the subnet. I can't use 10.240.0.0 or 10.240.0.1. But I still get the error message. Has anyone ever gotten a similar error message when upgrading to a VPC network? How did you solve it?

Thanks.

All devices are in us-central1

*Updating to include information*

gcloud beta compute networks update default --switch-to-custom-subnet-mode

Network [default] will be switched to custom mode. This operation cannot be undone.

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

X  Migrating Network from Legacy to Custom Mode

Validating Network

Creating Subnetwork

Updating Instances

Updating Instance Groups

Updating Forwarding Rules

Converting Network to Subnet Mode

Failed.

**ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.networks.update) The first 2 IPs in this network's range 10.240.0.0/16 must be in used.**

*Network info*

default
Description Default network for the project

Subnet creation mode: Legacy VPC network

Dynamic routing mode: Regional

VPC network ULA internal IPv6 range: Disabled

DNS server policy: None

Maximum transmission unit: 1460

Addresses: 10.240.0.0/16

Gateway: 10.240.0.1

*Internal IP addresses*

10.240.0.3
10.240.0.4
10.240.0.7
10.240.0.11
10.240.0.15
10.240.0.19
10.240.0.21
10.240.0.27
10.240.0.40
10.240.0.46
10.240.0.53
10.240.0.56
10.240.0.65
10.240.0.76
10.240.0.87
10.240.0.99
10.240.0.108
10.240.0.109
10.240.0.111
10.240.0.116

Comment: Double-check the wording of the error message that you copied into the question. Include the current legacy network configuration. Create a network map of in-use IP addresses and associated resources in the legacy network. Edit your question once you have those details.

Comment: Is there any more information I can add to shed any light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your issue resolved?. If not, try to use the flags in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/networks/update) this may help to resolve your issue.